# VSCode - GitLens

Tags: macos, git, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

This is so annoying to the **max**.

## VSCode - GitLens

I have no idea how to get rid of this message in the bottom right of my VSCode.

[image]

---

[image]

I've uninstall, disabled, nothing success

I've uninstalled my VSCode completely. This still happen.

**Unbelievable**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to uninstall Gitlens, select the Extensions tab in your sidebar, it looks like this:

[image]

Then find and click on Gitlens. You'll have the option to Disable or Uninstall, either will stop the error from popping up but if you're using it, it's probably fine to just uninstall it.

Comment: The errors in post showing that I can’t Uninstall it disabled.